# UIPageControl - iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipagecontrol

I have 5 pics to display (one at a time) in a UIPageControl way, so whenever i scroll (right or left) another pic will show. i can't find a sample code for that! 
i searched a lot and apple's sample code is complicated i need a simpler one.

Comment: Check [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html) tutorial from Cocoa with love. It's very simple.

Comment: try downloading the "Xcode Sample Project" from this site. http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you are looking for is *UIScrollView with pagination*. **UIPageControl** is the small dots that is mostly(not necessarily) positioned on the bottom of scroll view. You have to configure it separately.

To enable paging in a scroll view, you need to set its **pagingEnabled** property to **YES**.
The following [**UIScrollView paging tutorial**](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/) may help you.